# JSP Wiki on Windows 7 - Play WMV videos

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, windows-7, windows-media-player

I have configured JSP Wiki with Tomcat 7 on Windows 7 machine. I have few  videos on my wiki pages which resides in the Webapps folder of tomcat. I can access web application and see the pages. But i could not play the videos on any of my browser (IE 8, Chrome , Firefox) in my web application. I have embed the video as WMV as,

```
<embed playcount="0" autorewind="1" autostart="0" showpositioncontrols="1" type="application/x-mplayer2" src="/Webapp1/attach/test.wmv">
```

and i have placed the jar mediaplayer2.jar under webapps/Webapp1/WEB-INF/lib folder. But i could not play the video.

Any ideas to solve this?

[image]